# Reference : N dimensional rectangle inscribed in an N dimensional ellipsoid

Tags: geometry

In specific, given an 5-dimensional ellipsoid with intercepts,(a1, a2, ..., a5), with the Cartesian coordinates, what are the set of linear equations that describe 5 - dimensional rectangle inscribed in ellipsoid with vertices at the intersection of 5-dim ellipsoid with the Cartesian coordinates. Also what is the fraction of volume covered by inscribed rectangle.
Further I am looking to generalise this for n -dim and non-euclidean geometry. So any references that builds up for specific cases and generalizes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do the case when all $a_i = 1$, so the ellipsoid is just the unit Euclidean ball.  Then get the general case by applying a linear transformation whose matrix has $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$ on the diagonal and zeroes elsewhere (which changes all volumes by a factor of $a_1\cdot a_2\dotsb a_n$).

The volume of the $n$-dimensional Euclidean ball of radius $1$ is $\pi^{n/2}/\Gamma(1+\frac{n}{2})$.  There are many ways to compute this; Wikipedia has [a few](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deriving_the_volume_of_an_n-ball).  Another nice method involves computing $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|x|^2} \,dx$ in two ways; see the first few pages of Keith Ball's *An Elementary Introduction to Modern Convex Geometry*, available [here](http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/contents.html).

I'm not totally sure what you mean by "5-dimensional rectangle", but since you say it has vertices where the Cartesian coordinate axes meet the ball, I think you mean a *cross-polytope*.  The volume of the standard cross-polytope (the one inscribed in the unit ball) is $2^n/n!$.  I think this is computed in Coxeter's *Regular Polytopes*, but I'm not sure, so here's the proof: cut the cross-polytope into $2^n$ pieces, one in each orthant; each piece is a "right-angled simplex", by which I mean (something congruent to) the convex hull of the origin and the standard basis vectors $e_1,\dotsc,e_n$.  This simplex is a cone with vertex at $e_n$, of height $1$, and whose base is a right-angled simplex of the next lower dimension; by induction, it has volume $1/n!$.

So the proportion of the volume of the ball which is contained in the inscribed cross-polytope is
$$ \frac{\Gamma(1+\frac{n}{2}) 2^n}{\pi^{n/2} n!} $$
(By Stirling's formula, as $n\to\infty$ this is asymptotically $\frac1{\sqrt2} \left(\frac{2e}{\pi n}\right)^{n/2}$, which goes to zero very rapidly as the dimension grows.  The inscribed cube captures much more of the volume.)

The cross-polytope is given by the inequality
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| \le 1 $$
(where $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ are the Cartesian coordinates).  You can resolve this into $2^n$ linear inequalities if you like, one for each way of choosing signs for the $x_i$.  For example, in the $3$-dimensional case, you'd have
$$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \le 1 $$
$$ x_1 + x_2 - x_3 \le 1 $$
$$ x_1 - x_2 + x_3 \le 1 $$
$$ x_1 - x_2 - x_3 \le 1 $$
$$ - x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \le 1 $$
$$ - x_1 + x_2 - x_3 \le 1 $$
$$ - x_1 - x_2 + x_3 \le 1 $$
$$ - x_1 - x_2 - x_3 \le 1 $$
I don't know of a reference that explains this carefully.  [**Edit:** I meant I didn't know a reference that explains the cross-polytope carefully.  But the general theory of expressing convex bodies via linear inequalities is standard, and probably any introductory text on convex geometry will discuss it.  Try, say, Lay's *Convex Sets and Their Applications*, the section on separating hyperplanes and the section on polarity.  The $2^n$ inequalities above arise because the polar of the cross-polytope is the $n$-dimensional cube, which has $2^n$ vertices.]

I don't know anything about non-Euclidean geometry.